# Hamburger sidemenu

Tags: menu, hamburger

[image]

Not sure what this menu icon is commonly referred to as I cant find any example of where this is used but this is in a current projects side menu that expands horizontally on several levels.

How would this icon be presented when the menu is in an open state?

Comment: gawker (and related sites) has it equivalent and does not change state, it only display the menu below the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the whole 'hamburger' debate, I would probably consider that if you're having trouble representing the different states and meanings of this icon - how will your users understand it?

If I can offer some advice though, a little tip is to use the noun project and search for icons under their search terms - the guys there have done a pretty great job at categorising the icons by their most common representation.

The only way you can test this is a form of card sorting - place the symbol up on the wall and ask your target audience what they think it represents. (pin the tail on the donkey style - no blindfold!). Then 'reverse' card sort and put the words on the wall and ask a second group of participants to put the icon against the word they think the symbol matches with.

Good luck!